# rvest -- how to scrape a table in a tab?

Tags: r, web-scraping, tidyverse, rvest

I am trying to scrape a table in a tab using rvest but `html_elements()` seems to ignore it.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

URL.BNPF <- 'https://fundkis.com/en/funds/bnppf-privatesustainable-balanced/BE6294262298#navs'
html <- read_html(URL.BNPF)

test <- html %>% 
    html_elements('#navs') %>%
    html_elements('.row')
```

Code works until there, but anything I tried after to extract the table itself (under the title "Historical Net Asset Values (Quotes)") returns an empty list. I suspect the fact the table is under a tab may impact the `class` or `id` I need to look for.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is dynamically pulled from an API call. You can pick up the *key* from the initial url and pass that into the API call and get the data back as json. I altered the pageSize param of the API call to be large enough to get all likely results.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(jsonlite)

r <- read_html('https://fundkis.com/en/funds/bnppf-privatesustainable-balanced/BE6294262298#navs') 

share_id <- stringr::str_match(r %>% html_node('[name=ReactRiskPart]') %>% html_attr('props'), '"shareId": "(.*?)"')[,2]

api_url <- sprintf('https://fundkis.com/api/fkdb/navs/%s?PageIndex=0&PageSize=2000', share_id)

data<- jsonlite::read_json(api_url)
```

---

As dataframe:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

r <- read_html("https://fundkis.com/en/funds/bnppf-privatesustainable-balanced/BE6294262298#navs")

share_id <- stringr::str_match(r %>% html_node("[name=ReactRiskPart]") %>% html_attr("props"), '"shareId": "(.*?)"')[, 2]

api_url <- sprintf("https://fundkis.com/api/fkdb/navs/%s?PageIndex=0&PageSize=2000", share_id)

data <- jsonlite::read_json(api_url)

df <- map_dfr(data, data.frame) %>%
  mutate(Date = format.Date(NavDate)) %>%
  select(-c("FundShareId", "NavDate")) %>%
  rename(Currency = NavCurrencyISO, `Net Asset` = TotalAum, VL = Nav, `Nb Shares` = NbShares) %>%
  relocate(Date, Currency, VL, `Nb Shares`, `Net Asset`)
```

Comment: you can also get a data frame this way: `data <- read_json(api_url, simplifyVector = TRUE)`